# How to sum values of tow columns in a datagridview and put the result in third one?

Tags: c#

How can I sum the values of two dataGridView columns and store the result in a third column for each row ?
I have a datagridview with these columns:

```cs
dgIdamas.Columns[0].FillWeight = 260;
dgIdamas.Columns[0].HeaderText = "FailName";
dgIdamas.Columns[1].FillWeight = 100;
dgIdamas.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Num1";
dgIdamas.Columns[2].FillWeight = 60;
dgIdamas.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Type";
dgIdamas.Columns[3].FillWeight = 60;
dgIdamas.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Num2";
```

I want to sum value of "Num1" + "Num2" in a new column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully you set things up using data binding, which makes this trivial:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("failname");
dt.Columns.Add("num1", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("type");
dt.Columns.Add("num2", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("total", typeof(int)).Expression = "[num1] + [num2]";

dt.Rows.Add("over temperature", 1, "square", 2);
dt.Rows.Add("over weight", 7, "triangle", 9);

dgIdamas.DataSource = dt;
```

`DataColumnCollection.Add(string, type)` creates and returns the added column

This means on the fifth line (`dt.Columns.Add("total", typeof(int)).Expression = "[num1] + [num2]";`) we can immediately then set the [Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-5.0) property of the new column, to a string that describes the formula you want - to add the two columns.

Now, any rows you add to this table will have a third column whose value is recomputed any time the other two columns change. The table is bound to the grid; any changes you make to the table are shown in the grid - you can add new rows to the grid, set the `num1` and `num2` and the grid shows the total automatically

[image]

Worth noting that if you're manually creating datagridview columns rather than relying on `AutoGenerateColumns = true` then you *will* need to add a grid column for the `total` just as you would for any other column..

Comment: Is there a n easier way?